# revolution slider (vertical slider) on window scroll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider, slider-revolution

hi I have a slider in revolution slider that is vertical slider and I want it work like usual page and when users scroll the page it change slides but it only changes slides when the mouse is in the slider area. And with window scrollbar doesn't do anything and stops. how can I do this? maybe some javascript code is needed or what?
I tried the scroll options in revolution slider(window,body,both) but it doesn't change

Comment: I think the question is specific to the plugin if I am right. Have you tried posting the question on their plugin support?

Comment: no but I have seen all sliders with this plugin are like this and there is no such setting in plugin so I think I need to write a code for it but I don't know what it is!

Comment: I would suggest you to ask them anyway if you haven't already because you never know if there is setting or not for that. Maybe it takes correct combination of settings to work the way you want. And if they say there is no such settings then you can decide to use JS.

Comment: Hi, we do have an option for this in the "module general options" > "on scroll" > "scroll based features" - "timeline" > "Fix during scroll". This turns this feature on, there are a few more settings below you can use to finetune this. In case you run into issues please do not hesitate to contact our support experts. Cheers!